# Linux Centos 5.5 yum update command is not working

Tags: centos, yum, upgrade

I have done lots of things to update.

1. `yum clean all`
2. `yum clean metadata`
3. `yum clean dbcache`

then `yum update` outputs:

```
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.6/addons/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found Trying other mirror.

Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: addons. Please verify its path and try again
```

I have also tried

- setting `enabled=0` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo`
- `yum -v update --disablerepo=contrib uname -a`
- `touch /.autorelabel`
- `yum -v update --disablerepo=contrib`

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the URL in a browser and remove path components from the end and you'll eventually find this: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.6/readme, which explains why it's not working. Have you modified your CentOS-Base.repo file earlier?

Update to the latest centos-release RPM manually, eg:

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/centos-release-5-7.el5.centos.i386.rpm
```

And make sure that the CentOS-Base.repo file from it is used and you should have better luck with yum afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

the latest centos-release RPM: 
 rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/centos-release-5-9.el5.centos.1.i386.rpm